# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'greenlet._greenlet'

Tags: python, greenlets

I'm trying to use the `TikTokPy` but there is an error occurring in `Greenlet` module:

```
$ python quickstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mngoc\tiktokpy\quickstart.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tiktokpy import TikTokPy
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\tiktokpy/tiktokpy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bot import TikTokPy
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\tiktokpy/tiktokpy/bot/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tiktokpy.client import Client
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\tiktokpy/tiktokpy/client/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from playwright.async_api import Browser, Page, Playwright, PlaywrightContextManager, Response
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages/playwright/async_api/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import playwright.async_api._generated
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 25, in <module>
    from playwright._impl._accessibility import Accessibility as AccessibilityImpl
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages/playwright/_impl/_accessibility.py", line 17, in <module>
    from playwright._impl._connection import Channel
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 23, in <module>
    from greenlet import greenlet
  File "C:/Users\mngoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages/greenlet/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._greenlet import _C_API # pylint:disable=no-name-in-module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'greenlet._greenlet'
```

I've already installed `Greenlet` module, but I have no idea about `._greenlet`, there isn't any answer for related question so I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you tried to [install greenlet](https://pypi.org/project/greenlet/)? If you first use `pip install greenlet` and try to use TikTokPy afterwards, it may solve your problem.

Comment: @PaschalisAg I already installed greenlet, I even reinstall it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should install the module:

```
pip3 install greenlet
```

Comment: I already installed the module

Comment: When you run `pip3 list`, is the module shown?

Comment: Yes, it was shown when I run `pip list` or `pip3 list`

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me after updating `greenlet` to 3.0.3.

I'm using:
Python 3.11
SQLAlchemy~=2.0.23
aiosqlite~=0.20.0